# Traceroute from VM guest does not go past Host PC to internet

Tags: ubuntu, udp, icmp, traceroute

I have created an Ubuntu virtual machine on my PC, and I was trying out the traceroute command, as I need it for a college project. However, when I ran "traceroute www.google.com", what I got was:

1 _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.494 ms  0.472 ms  0.461 ms

2  * * *

3  * * *

and so on, nothing but "* * *". It worked when I added the "-I" argument, but I would not be allowed to use that for my project. Is there any way to fix this, so that the I can do traceroute using UDP, not ICMP?

Might also be worth mentioning that when I ran traceroute on my Windows PC, the one the VM is running on, I didn't encounter any issues like this.

Comment: From Ubuntu VM, can you ping 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 ?

Comment: I just tried it, and I could ping both of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VM is connected through NAT adapter, you will experience this issue. To make it work, connect your VM through bridge adapter.

Comment: I'll look into switching that now

Comment: It works now!!! Thank you so much!!